# Reading from SD card and inserting to SQL table is extremely slow

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, insert, opencsv

I have a problem that has been driving me crazy and I'd appreciate any thoughts you guys may have to offer. I import data from a CSV file (using openCSV) into a database, and previously this process has been completed in about 3-5 seconds including the download time from a server. The CSV file has 3035 records. I've tried separating the parsing from CSV and inserting to the table, but to no avail.

As strange as it may sound suddenly something has changed within my application where now this process takes much much longer.

After narrowing it down I've found that inserting into the table is extremely slow for SQLite. I've spent the last couple hours reverting back to older code to see if something has changed but to no luck.

I came across some similar question whose answer suggest me to use InsertHelper, which I did. Which made absolutely no difference in the import time. Currently inserting data takes 60 seconds, where it used to take just a couple.

```
public void importFromCSV() 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM EXAMS");
    File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(SDCardRoot.getAbsolutePath() + "/Finals/Data/timetable.csv");
    CSVReader reader;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
        String [] nextLine;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {                
            this.addExam(new Exam(nextLine[0],
                                  nextLine[1],
                                  nextLine[2],
                                  nextLine[3],
                                  nextLine[4],
                                  nextLine[5],
                                  nextLine[6],
                                  nextLine[7],
                                  nextLine[8],
                                  nextLine[9]));
        }           

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public void addExam(Exam exam) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_SESSION, exam.getSession());
    values.put(KEY_AWARDING_BODY, exam.getAwardingBody());
    values.put(KEY_QUALIFICATION, exam.getQualification());
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, exam.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_EXAM_CODE, exam.getExamCode());
    values.put(KEY_DURATION, exam.getDuration());
    values.put(KEY_DATE, exam.getDate());
    values.put(KEY_START_TIME, exam.getStartTime());
    values.put(KEY_EXAM_NOTE, exam.getExamNote());
    values.put(KEY_MY_NOTES, exam.getMyNotes()); 
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

}
```

Comment: Do you test it on a device? Did you try another? The code you posted is about reading a file, not inserting to SQL. Maybe it would be better to post the inserting fragment? I think it may have something to do with reading from SD. SD cards become slower if there's little space left on them

Comment: Have you done any profiling on this instead of guessing? You should use the systrace tool and try to figure out where your bottleneck is.

Comment: I've tried on both a One X and a HD2, same this also occurs on the emulator. The addExam method inserts it into the database. So as it's read from the CSV file, it is entered right after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inserts may be slow because you are having to set up your references for every insert. Jeff Sharkey actually just talked about this problem in length at Google IO 1012. https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/103/ Basically you should be wrapping everything up in as few transactions as possible.

```
try{
  db.beginTransaction();
  for each record in the list {
     do_some_processing();
     if (line represent a valid  entry) {
        db.insert(SOME_TABLE, null, SOME_VALUE);
     }
     some_other_processing();
  }
  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException e) {
} finally {
  db.endTranscation();
}
```

Comment: Yes! This works. It does the work in 2 seconds as opposed to 60+. Thank you, appreciate it.